# Are aluminum antiperspirants unhealthy?

Tags: environmental-health, hygiene

It is regularly stated that aluminium is very bad for the brain, and for your general health. Is this true for antiperspirants?

Is Potassium alum more healthy or is this just about marketing ?

Comment: Please add a notable claim or source that state this.

Comment: Aside from the missing reference, this is asking two questions: Whether aluminum is bad for health, and whether Potassium alum is better for health. This should be two questions (each with references).